# Find the plane that passes through the intersection of two planes and a point

Tags: vector-spaces

> Find the scalar equation of the plane that passes through the line of intersection of two planes: $x+y+z-4 = 0$ and $y+z-2=0$ and the plane is 3 units from the point (5,-3,7).

I am able to form a plane that goes through the line of intersection of two planes by using a linear combination:

$$x+y+z-4 + k(y+z-2)=0$$

where $k$ is real number.

How do I find the value of k so that the plane is 3 units from the point?

Comment: Just because the plane contains a point 2 away from the origin, that doesn't mean it has distance 2 to the origin.

Comment: Your family of planes doesn’t include the plane $y+z-2=0$ itself. Fortunately, it’s not the solution to your problem, otherwise you’re really be stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve got a good start, although you really need to use a more general linear combination of the two planes instead: $$\lambda(x+y+z-4)+\mu(y+z-2)=0. \tag 1$$ The problem with your family of planes is that they exclude $y+z-2=0$ itself. That would leave you stuck with no solution if that plane happened to be the correct one. You can easily verify that the distance from $(5,-3,7)$ to this plane is not $3$, though, so in this case you can proceed with your original formulation.

Now you can simply use the formula for the distance of a point $P=(x_p,y_p,z_p)$ from the plane $ax+by+cz+d=0$: $${|ax_p+by_p+cz_p+d| \over \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}.$$ Plug in the coordinates of the point from the problem and use (1) for the plane, and set this equal to the required distance from the point. Squaring both sides and rearranging will give you a quadratic equation in $k$ to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Since the plane passes through the intersection of 2 other planes, lets start by finding the intersection line:

$ x+y+z-4 = 0$ and $ y + z - 2 = 0$

Finding two points on both planes to get the line equation. Points (2,0,2) and (2,2,0) are on the both plane, hence is enough to construct the line equation.

$$L1: (2,0,2) + k(0,1,-1) = 0$$

Since the plane has to contain L1, it's normal has to be normal to L1 as well. Let $n = (a,b,c)$, if n is normal to L1, the inner product has to be 0.

$$0*a + b*1 + c*-1 = 0$$

$$b=c$$

$$n = (a,b,b)$$

Writing the plane equation using the normal vector:

$$P1: ax + by + bz - d = 0$$

we know that 2,0,2 is on the plane, $2a+2b-d = 0$ Substituting d in the equation:

$$P1: ax + by + bz - 2a - 2b = 0$$

The vector from origin to the closest point has to be perpendicular to the plane. We can deduct that the closest point has the form (0,0,0) + k(n), the closest point to plane is, therefore k(a,b,b) is the closest point. Set the normal vector to have length 2 for ease of calculation.

$$a^2 + b^2 + b^2 = 2^2$$
Since (a,b,b) is on the plane and closest to origin
$$a^2 + b^2 + b^2 - 2a - 2b = 0 $$
$$4 - 2a - 2b = 0 $$
$$a = 2 - b$$
$$(2 - b)^2 + b^2 + b^2 = 2^2$$
$$4 -4.b +b^2 + 2.b^2 = 4$$
$$3.b^2=4.b$$
$$b_1 = 0, b_2 = \frac {4} 3, a_1 = 2, a_2 = \frac 2 3$$

Hence the two solutions are:

$P_1: x - 2 = 0$ with closest point (2,0,0)

$P_2: \frac 2 3 x + \frac 4 3 y + \frac 4 3 z - 4 = 0$ with closest point $(\frac 2 3,\frac 4 3,\frac 4 3)$

Comment: Once you claim that $x-2=0$ is equation of a line, then it is a plane. The lines don't have cartesian equation in 3D.

Comment: You are right, editing it

Comment: fixed it, thanks for the input

Comment: The distance from $P_2$ to $(5,-3,7)$ is not $3$.

Comment: @amd The original question was 2 points from the origin

Comment: In that case, your $P_1$ is also incorrect because its distance from the point is $3$. Either way, they can’t both be right because the two distances are different.

Comment: Both p1 and p2 have distance 2 to origin, contain the intersection line, hence they are right answers for the original question